# How to install and run Nutch in Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, installation, web-crawler, nutch

I want to run Nutch on my Windows 7 x64. I have Nutch versions 1.5.1 and 2 from [apache.spinellicreations.com/nutch/](http://nutch.apache.org/downloads.html).

I used the tutorial at [wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial). But I messed up in the second step and I can't verify the installation. Other steps are hard to understand...

What are the steps to install and use nutch?

Answer (score 7):

> Follow steps to install `nutch` in windows **:**

```
1) download and install cygwin from : https://www.cygwin.com/
2) download nutch from : http://nutch.apache.org/downloads.html
3) paste nutch downloaded and extracted folder into C:\cygwin64\home\
4) rename to apache-nutch
5) open cygwin terminal and type given commands 

 - $ cd C:
 - $ cd cygwin64
 - $ cd home
 - $ cd apache-nutch
 - $ cd src/bin
 - $ ./nutch
```

> you will get given output **:**

```
Usage: nutch COMMAND
where COMMAND is one of:
 inject         inject new urls into the database
 hostinject     creates or updates an existing host table from a text file
 generate       generate new batches to fetch from crawl db
 fetch          fetch URLs marked during generate
 parse          parse URLs marked during fetch
 updatedb       update web table after parsing
 updatehostdb   update host table after parsing
 readdb         read/dump records from page database
 readhostdb     display entries from the hostDB
 index          run the plugin-based indexer on parsed batches
 elasticindex   run the elasticsearch indexer - DEPRECATED use the index command instead
 solrindex      run the solr indexer on parsed batches - DEPRECATED use the index command instead
 solrdedup      remove duplicates from solr
 solrclean      remove HTTP 301 and 404 documents from solr - DEPRECATED use the clean command instead
 clean          remove HTTP 301 and 404 documents and duplicates from indexing backends configured via plugins
 parsechecker   check the parser for a given url
 indexchecker   check the indexing filters for a given url
 plugin         load a plugin and run one of its classes main()
 nutchserver    run a (local) Nutch server on a user defined port
 webapp         run a local Nutch web application
 junit          runs the given JUnit test
 or
 CLASSNAME      run the class named CLASSNAME
Most commands print help when invoked w/o parameters.
```

Comment: I flowed that above steps.when i check instalation goes correct using                  /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/apache-nutch-1.13/src/bin
$ nutch
 it gives this    -bash: nutch: command not found
why does it happen?

Comment: Run it using “./nutch” not “nutch”

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mess up the second step - you simply don't have (I'm guessing) Cygwin installed so you can't run a bash script. Either install Cygwin (simplest) or you could try porting the bash script to a Windows cmd file. (If you do that, you may find other dependencies down the line.

Hope this helps.